# Should I always call a min raise on the river?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand-reading, muck

When someones been checking/calling all the way to the river and then min raises on it, is it worth always calling to see their hand even if I know I definitely have the worst hand possible? (essentially I'm paying a blind so they can't muck their hand)

Comment: There is no "always" in poker.

Comment: @Mawg your comment should be a wisdom quote :)

Answer (score 0):

No if you have the worst hand and you don't want to bluff then fold

Answer (score 0):

How do you know you have the `worst` hand if you don't call him?
Some times (or more) we have to call our marginal holdings down, otherwise villains will take notice and bluff us relentlessly, `especially` on **River**. An example:

Hole cards
8♥ 7♥

Board cards
K⋄7♠3⋄T♠5⋄

Background: Villain is known to be checking/calling i.e. `a station` and bluff many rivers if met passivity.

You bet the **flop**, he calls. **Turn** is check/check. **River** you check, he min-bets.

No matter what, i'm calling here `for information for later hands`. In addition, i have a bottom-pair which certainly is something and not always `worst`. You don't know the Villain yet. He may be betting to represent `diamonds flush`. Because otherwise `he does not represent ANYTHING`. Or perhaps he bets a `T` which thinks it's best now. Or a `K` if he's that passive. The 5⋄ is as brick as possible. Regardless, you win too much information about your Villain and how he plays by just calling that down as cheap as that.

I casually call here min-bets with bottom-pair. You always win something, if not the hand, your opponent `tendencies` on the `River`.

Finally, don't bet against `Calling stations` (as he seems to be). They'll call anyway and you built an extensive history with him `cheaper` :)

Comment: Its very possible to know you have the worst hand without calling (i.e. 24o wrt the board you mentioned). The question is if its worth it to see the hand for blind money, with no chance of winning.

Comment: OP said if it's worth calling with the worst hand and i've answered with some reasons to do that i.e. information. OP didn't shows a hand so i don't know about `zero` chances of winning, that's relevant to personal perception.